# Maerionette giving ReferenceError: menuGroup is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, marionette

I have this template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="menu-template">
  <a ><li data-menuGroup="<%= menuGroup %>" class="<%=liClass%>" id="<%= liId%>"><%=name%></li></a>
</script>
```

this JSON:

```
{"id":5,"menuId":2,"name":"Home","liId":"reports_home_sub_menu","liClass":"tab","targetDiv":"reportHome","contentName":"qado_reports_home","url":"","callback":"","orderBy":1,"privilage":"","menuGroup":"reportsTab"}
```

and this Marionette Javascript:

```
View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#menu-template"
});
var model = new Backbone.Model(json);   
var view = new View(model);
view.render();
$("#menuContainer").append(view.el);
```

but when I run this, I get a " ReferenceError: menuGroup is not defined" error in the console. I am very new to Marionette so it's probably something stupid.  But the JSON clearly has an item "menuGroup" in it, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. First, make sure your JSON-string is parsed into a JavaScript object. Secondly, the `View` constructor function does not take a model as a
parameter, but an `options` object, which has a `model`-field.

```
var modelData = JSON.parse(json);
var model = new Backbone.Model(modelData);   
var view = new View({model: model});
```

Comment: I afraid that's not working either.  It throws the exception right at the view.render() function.

Comment: @mmaceachran Ah, I see. Shoot. Is your JSON-string parsed into a JavaScript object before you pass it to the model? If not, try `var modelData = JSON.parse(json); var model = new Backbone.Model(modelData);`

Comment: That did it.  Must be an object.  Thank you!

Comment: @mmaceachran Great! No problem.